# Unable to run the maven project using Spring, Hibernate and tomcat 9

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat9

I'm trying to run the project but it's giving the below error. I'm using spring, hibernate, tomcat 9 and MySQL. I have tried many things on the internet but still, it's not working. I have done some changes in the pom.xml file by find some of the solutions on the internet but still, no results. Anyone can help me out on this ?

```
Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.50
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Jun 28 2021 08:46:44 UTC
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version number: 9.0.50.0
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            10.0
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205\jre
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           16.0.1+9-24
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\Sts_Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\Sts_Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\Sts_Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/sts-4.11.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205/jre/bin/server;C:/sts-4.11.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.9_12\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Windows\IsmFilesC:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE;;.]
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Server initialization in [1850] milliseconds
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:22 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
    WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,071] milliseconds.
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:39 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in grocery.stock.management.config.AppContext: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager.reset()'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager.reset()'
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:406)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:744)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        ... 42 more
    
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/grocery.stock.management] startup failed due to previous errors
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
    WARNING: The web application [grocery.stock.management] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
    WARNING: The web application [grocery.stock.management] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.base@16.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     java.base@16.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
     com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:64)
     java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
     java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
     java.base@16.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalsForLeaks
    WARNING: When running on Java 9 or later you need to add "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=null" to the JVM command line arguments to enable ThreadLocal memory leak detection. Alternatively, you can suppress this warning by disabling ThreadLocal memory leak detection.
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
    INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Jul 12, 2021 1:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in [24501] milliseconds
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager.reset()'` These kind of errors/exception generally occur when yo mess around with dependencies too much. You are probably mixing jars/modules from different versions of a framework (here probably hibernate).

Comment: @M.Deinum should I use the latest version of everything or some specific version sequence you have?

Comment: You want to us hibernate 5, so use jars from hibernate 5, you are probably mixing 3 and 5 or something alike. Or you are using HInernate 6 or a too new Hibenate 5 dependency to use with the Spring version you have. There is basically too little information to answer this question.

Comment: @M.Deinum still not working, I'm using now the latest versions of everything

Comment: Without knowing versions of what and in which combinations this will simply be impossible to answer. You are using a combination that doesn't work, arbitrary changing versions and hoping things will start to work isn't the way.